# Event Listener "touchstart" lags

Tags: javascript, android, lag, event-listener

I have an event listener in javascript. But, when activated, the entire program lags for almost a half second per click. Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks in advance!

I am using Intel XDK to build this, and on the simulate tab, this does not happen. It runs smoothly.

```
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", getPosition, false)
var pointerX = 0;
var pointerY = 0;
function getPosition(event) {
    pointerX = event.touches[0].clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    pointerY = event.touches[0].clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
}
```